# How to delete image with ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I am trying to delete a record from my products table, each product has an image. I don't know how to delete the image from the file where it is stored.

***Product.js***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    

    $("#btn-delete").click(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/product/' + $("#frmDeleteProduct input[name=product_id]").val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#frmDeleteProduct .close").click();
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

function deleteProductForm(product_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/product/' + product_id,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#frmDeleteProduct #delete-title").html("¿Do you want to delete this product (" + data.products.name + ")?");
            $("#frmDeleteProduct input[name=product_id]").val(data.products.id);
            $('#deleteProductModal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

***ProductController.php***

I read that I need to put something like this in my controller `File::delete('img/products/' . $image);` but I don't now how.

```php
public function destroy($id)
    {

        //File::delete('img/products/' . $image); 
        $products = Product::destroy($id);

        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'products'  => $products,
        ], 200);
    }
```

Comment: In your destroy method, you should check in database if such image with that id exists and if yes, get the image path, and then use "unlink" method of PHP or use Storage::delete function with the path of your file.

Comment: I use this id to verify the product. The image has a different name. How should I do? @AliKhalili

Comment: You need to get the image of the product before deleting product and then `Storage::delete($product->image)`, then you can proceed with product deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass as a parameter to `File::delete()` the full path when your image was save. For example, if your images were in a laravel storage path in the subdirectory `img/products/`, and the name of the image is the id of the product with the `.jpg` extension, you can do this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $fullImgPath = storage_path("img/products/$id.jpg");
    if(File::exists($fullImgPath)) {
        File::delete($fullImgPath);
    }

    $products = Product::destroy($id);

    return response()->json([
        'error' => false,
        'products'  => $products,
    ], 200);
}
```

But if you have the name of the image in your `Product` model, you can do this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    $fullImgPath = storage_path("img/products/".$product->image_name);
    if(File::exists($fullImgPath)) {
        File::delete($fullImgPath);
    }

    $product->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'error' => false,
        'products'  => $product->id,
    ], 200);
}
```